# Checking Reports against a changing Data Model

Tags: sharepoint, reporting-services, rdl

I am working on a SharePoint application where the data is kept in lists. For ease of reporting, we create views in SQL Server 2005 that link lists together, and our Reporting Services model is based on these views.

As users add/modify/delete fields, our views become stale. When we recreate the views, some reports are no longer valid. What is the best way to allow users to modify fields and update the existing reports automatically (or notify an admin that a report has been broken by changing a field)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you thought about reporting directly off the Lists, maybe using a product like http://www.enesyssoftware.com/ which is a reporting service data extension. This still won't help with your reports going stale when your users add/remove column.